# Google Bar Chart cannot Change Individual Bar Color

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I've created a google bar chart using the Google Visualization API and I'm trying to add a column which will be used for style. Here's my implementation below using the .addcolumn() and then adding the color field to each row, however each bar is still the default blue color.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Runs onload to build the first default chart and load the bar chart package
var jsonCoachCount;
window.onload = function(){
    jsonCoachCount = JSON.parse('[{"Service_Count":"4","Name":"Other"},  {"Service_Count":"4","Name":"Campus Network"},{"Service_Count":"3","Name":"Learn@UW"},{"Service_Count":"2","Name":"Customer Service"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Blackboard Collaborate"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Office 365"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Multiple"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Office-ionado"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Case Notes"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"ResNet"}]');

// Load the Visualization API and the barchart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['bar']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

};
function drawChart(){

    var servicesData = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    servicesData.addColumn('string', 'Service');
    servicesData.addColumn('number', 'Number of Coaches');
    servicesData.addColumn({type:'string', role:'style'});

    for(i = 0; i < jsonCoachCount.length; i++){
        tempArray =[];
        tempArray.push(String (jsonCoachCount[i]['Name']),
                parseInt(jsonCoachCount[i]['Service_Count']),
                'color:Red');
        servicesData.addRow(tempArray);
    }

    var options = {
        backgroundColor: {
            fill: '#E8E4D8'
        },
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        titleTextStyle:{
            bold: 'true'
        },
        chart: {
            title: 'Coaches by Service',
            subtitle: 'Coaches by Services: From 2016-09-10 until Today'
        },
        bar: {
            groupWidth: '60%'
        },
        'hAxis': {
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: 11
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('servicesChart'));

    chart.draw(servicesData, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

}
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
```

```
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or if I've misunderstood a piece of the documentation. I'd appreciate help for changing the color of the bars on my bar chart, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

each color in the `colors` option is applied to each series / y-axis column in the data table.
if there is only one y-axis column, only one color will be applied.

Otherwise, a [Style Column Role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) is the easiest way to color an individual bar.
However, it does not work on Material Charts.

For options, see example charts...

> Chart 1 = Material Chart
>   Chart 2 = Core Chart
>   Both built the same way with various style settings
>   Works on Core, not on Material

If you are fine with each bar being the same color...

> Chart 3 = Material Chart
>   Uses `colors` configuration option to change the color to red
>   Only one series exists, so accepts only one color

If you must have Material Chart with separate colors for each bar...

> Chart 4 = Material Chart
>   Each value is added as a column, instead of a row, creating multiple series
>   Uses `colors` configuration option to change color for each bar
>   `series` option can also be used here
>   However, much harder to work with, notice `Spacer` column and lack of `hAxis` labels...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: init,
  packages: ['bar', 'corechart']
});

function init() {
  var jsonCoachCount = JSON.parse('[{"Service_Count":"4","Name":"Other"},  {"Service_Count":"4","Name":"Campus Network"},{"Service_Count":"3","Name":"Learn@UW"},{"Service_Count":"2","Name":"Customer Service"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Blackboard Collaborate"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Office 365"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Multiple"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Office-ionado"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"Case Notes"},{"Service_Count":"1","Name":"ResNet"}]');

  var options = {
      backgroundColor: {
          fill: '#E8E4D8'
      },
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      titleTextStyle:{
          bold: 'true'
      },
      chart: {
          title: 'Coaches by Service',
          subtitle: 'Coaches by Services: From 2016-09-10 until Today'
      },
      bar: {
          groupWidth: '60%'
      },
      hAxis: {
          textStyle: {
              fontSize: 11
          }
      }
  };

  drawChart();
  drawSeriesChart();

  function drawChart() {
      var servicesData = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      servicesData.addColumn('string', 'Service');
      servicesData.addColumn('number', 'Number of Coaches');
      servicesData.addColumn({type:'string', role:'style'});

      for (i = 0; i < jsonCoachCount.length; i++) {
          var tempArray =[];
          var tempColor;
          switch (i) {
            case 0:
              tempColor = 'color:Red';
              break;

            case 1:
              tempColor = 'orange';
              break;

            case 2:
              tempColor = 'fill-color: gold;';
              break;

            case 3:
              tempColor = 'bar {color: green;}';
              break;

            case 4:
              tempColor = 'bar {fill-color: blue;}';
              break;

            default:
              tempColor = 'bar {fill-color: cyan; stroke-color: black; stroke-width: 4;}';
          }
          tempArray.push(
            String (jsonCoachCount[i]['Name']),
            parseInt(jsonCoachCount[i]['Service_Count']),
            tempColor
          );
          servicesData.addRow(tempArray);
      }

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('servicesChart1'));
      chart.draw(servicesData, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('servicesChart2'));
      chart.draw(servicesData, options);

      // only one series exists -- only one color will work
      options.colors = ['red'];
      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('servicesChart3'));
      chart.draw(servicesData, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }

  function drawSeriesChart() {
      var servicesData = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      servicesData.addColumn('string', 'Service');
      for (i = 0; i < jsonCoachCount.length; i++) {
        servicesData.addColumn('number', String (jsonCoachCount[i]['Name']));
        servicesData.addColumn('number', 'Spacer');
      }

      var tempArray = [];
      tempArray.push('Number of Coaches');
      for (i = 0; i < jsonCoachCount.length; i++) {
        tempArray.push(parseInt(jsonCoachCount[i]['Service_Count']));
        tempArray.push(null);
      }
      servicesData.addRow(tempArray);

      options.colors = [
        'deeppink',
        'red',
        'orange',
        'gold',
        'green',
        'blue',
        'indigo',
        'purple',
        'violet',
        'pink'
      ];

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('servicesChart4'));
      chart.draw(servicesData, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.code {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-family: Courier New;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>1. Material Chart</div>
<div id="servicesChart1"></div>
<div>2. Core Chart</div>
<div id="servicesChart2"></div>
<div>3. Material Chart with <span class="code">colors: ['red']</span></div>
<div id="servicesChart3"></div>
<div>4. Multi-Series Material Chart</div>
<div id="servicesChart4"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the labels to work with horizontal material bars?

Comment: sorry, which labels? are you referring to annotations? if so, not with standard chart options, but you can try adding your own...