# Google Charts only using first color

Tags: javascript, html, colors, google-visualization

I am having trouble with Google Charts Bar Chart option to change colors of my bars - I have 3 bars and 3 colors listed in the options, but the bars are only showing the first color. Any ideas why?

```
function drawChart2() {
    var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Vote Choice', 'Votes'],
        [$scope.PropVotes[3].description, $scope.PropVotes[3].numVotes],
        [$scope.PropVotes[4].description, $scope.PropVotes[4].numVotes],
        [$scope.PropVotes[5].description, $scope.PropVotes[5].numVotes]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: $scope.Propositions[1].Title,
        legend: {
            position: 'top'
        },
        colors: ['#002c58', '#69BE28', '#A5ACAF'],
        chartArea: {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        },
        bars: 'horizontal',
        animation: {
            startup: true,
            duration: 5000,
            easing: 'linear'
        }
    };

    var chartName = 'chart_div2'; //' + $scope.PropVotes.id;
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById(chartName));
    chart.draw(chartdata, options);
}
```

Comment: That's because each bar is in the same series, `'Votes'`. To have a different color for each bar, you need to transform the rows to columns in your data. Other options available don't seem to work on _Material Charts_, take a look at [this answer for examples...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771)