# ng-google-chart custom color for each column in column chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I'm using the ng-google-charts module to build google charts for my angular application, what I'm trying to do is draw a column chart.

The code works the chart seems to be drawn correctly but I can't figure out how to add a colour in the rows I'm generating so that each column is coloured differently.

Here is my code, looking at google charts documentation it seems that I should be able to assign a hex code for each column but none of the examples I've seen use angular and none of them build their rows as literal objects like I need to do.

```
var collsArray = [];
    var rowsArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < vm.projects.length ; i++) {
        //this is where I build each data row and where I think I need to add the color
        rowsArray.push({
             "c": [
                {
                    "v": vm.projects[i].name
                },
                {
                    "v": vm.projects[i].developers,
                    "f": vm.projects[i].developers + ' developers working on ' + vm.projects[i].name
                }]
        });

    }
    collsArray = [{id: 'project', label: 'Project', type: 'string'},
           {id: 'developers', label: 'Developers working', type: 'number'}];

    vm.chartProjects = {
          "type": "ColumnChart",
          "displayed": false,
          "data": {
            "cols": collsArray,
            "rows": rowsArray
          },
          "options": {
            "isStacked": "true",
            "fill": 0,
            "width": '100%',
            "height": '100%',
            "displayExactValues": true,
            "chartArea": {
                "left": "1%",
                "top": "1%",
                "height": "98%",
                "width": "98%"
            }
          },
          "formatters": {},
          "view": {}
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a [Style Column Role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) is the easiest way to color an individual bar.

You could try something like this...

```
var colorPallette = [
  '#7B241C', '#CB4335', '#FF9900', 'Gold', '#28B463',
  '#196F3D', '#0D47A1', '#29B6F6', 'Indigo', 'Violet'
];

var collsArray = [];
var rowsArray = [];

collsArray = [
  {id: 'project', label: 'Project', type: 'string'},
  {id: 'developers', label: 'Developers working', type: 'number'},
  {role: 'style', type: 'string'}  // style column
];

var colorIndex = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < vm.projects.length ; i++) {
  // manage color pallette
  colorIndex++;
  if (colorIndex === colorPallette.length) {
    colorIndex = 0;
  }
  rowsArray.push({
    "c": [
      {
        "v": vm.projects[i].name
      },
      {
        "v": vm.projects[i].developers,
        "f": vm.projects[i].developers + ' developers working on ' + vm.projects[i].name
      },
      {
        "v": colorPallette[colorIndex]  // style column
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) shows the various color definitions you could use.
FYI: this option *does not* work with *Material* charts...

Comment: if you don't want to mess with a color pallette, you could add each bar value as a column instead of a row, which would force the chart to display each a different color.

Comment: your answer works but what would be best practice to use the colors array or to add the bar values as columns ?

Comment: not sure about _best practice_ but i prefer using the style column, as it allows complete control and more options than just color. transforming rows to columns can be confusing and also makes customizing bar spacing, axis labels, legend entries, etc. more difficult, since a separate series is created for each...