# googlecharts - different colors for barchart not working by setting 'colors' option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, google-visualization

I am generating a barchart with googlecharts and i want to show each bar  in different color. I try to set "colors" in options but only one color is showing on all the bar in my case 'blue' but i want to show all different colors. here is my code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var theData = [ // Start of JavaScript data object
            <%
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            String connectionURL = "someurl";
            Connection connection = null;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT order_channel, ROUND(orders / SUM(orders) over () * 100, 2) pct, ROUND(orders) orders FROM ( SELECT order_channel, COUNT(*) AS orders FROM order_channel GROUP BY order_channel ) ORDER BY 3 DESC");
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
            %>
                    [ "<%= rs.getString(1)%>",<%= rs.getString(2)%>,<%= rs.getString(3)%>],
            <%
                };
                // End of JavaScript object holding the data
            %>
                ];
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:['corechart', 'bar']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
           function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['OrderChannel', 'PCT', 'Orders']].concat(theData), false);

                var options = {
                        title: 'National  Orders',
                        isStacked: true,
                        hAxis: {
                            title: 'Total Count'

                          },
                          vAxis: {
                            title: 'Order Channel'
                          },
                          colors: ['red','blue','green','yellow','pink','magenta','cyan', 'gray','orange','lime']
                       };
                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771), although it focuses on _Material_ vs. _Core_ charts, it explains options for coloring bars...

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the charts render with one colour per data column. So if you have time-series data(which is most common), then you have the date used for an axis, and then each column attached to the same row will iterate through the colours list and take a different colour, starting back at the beginning when it runs out of colours. Therefore, if you have one data column, it will use one colour. If you have 2 data columns, it will use two colours. If you want a different colour for every row of your data table, you need to use a column with a style role.