# Google Material chart Column Chart (Bar chart) custom column color not working

Tags: javascript, android, charts, google-visualization

I want to draw a simple **column chart** in `HTML-JavaScript` using `google chart`.I have used `Google materiel chart CDN` to draw a column chart **having 4 rows with 4 different colors**.

I have tried plenty of options but nothing is working properly. when I have used the `colors: ['#b0120a', '#004411', '#ffab91', '#004411']` only the first color is being displayed in all the 4 columns. I have also tried `{role:'style'}` but still not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        /*var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Class', 'Total',{role: 'style'}],
          ['A', 10,'color: #b0120a'],
          ['B', 30,'color: #004411'],
          ['C', 20,'color: #ffab91'],
          ['D', 30,'color: #004411']
        ]);*/
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Class', 'Total'],
          ['A', 10],
          ['B', 30],
          ['C', 20],
          ['D', 30]
        ]);

        var options = {
          isStacked: true,
          title: 'Class wise total students',
          colors: ['#b0120a', '#004411', '#ffab91', '#004411'],
         };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The chart is like: 
[image]

But I want 4 different colors for 4 columns.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Bar Chart cannot Change Individual Bar Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437422/google-bar-chart-cannot-change-individual-bar-color)

Comment: I have searched all these related question on stackoverflow but haven't found any slimier  to my question that is why I've posted my question separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaa, at last I made this one correct and exactly I wanted to be. Please see the code below, if you required sometime.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {    
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Class', 'Total',{role: 'style'}],
          ['A', 10,'color: #b0120a'],
          ['B', 30,'color: #004411'],
          ['C', 20,'color: #ffab91'],
          ['D', 30,'color: #004411']
        ]);

        var options = {
          isStacked: false,
          title: 'Class wise total students',
         };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to changed the definition of `chart` here. From `var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));` to the modified one as `var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));`. It's working now.
The chart is like ....
[image]

Comment: you got it, [column roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available), including `'style'`, do not work on _Material_ charts, only _Core_ charts. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) are some other options...

Comment: The example show that colours can be set, but I think that this solution is just converting a material chart  back to classic column chart. The nice advantages of material chart (rounded corners, modern design) will disappear.