# Google Bar chart Bar color not changing

Tags: javascript, java, google-visualization

I'm using google bar chart to  represent set of issues into different categories like open, closed, in progress etc., I'm getting the count of different categories and storing it to a hashmap, and then I retrieve the data from hashmap and displaying it in the bar chart using the below code.

Edited below is the code that I'm using. I've included it in a jsp page

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarChart);

      function drawBarChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Status', 'No. of Issues', { role: 'style' }], 
          <%for(String SC:StatusCount.keySet()){
            %>
            ['<%=SC.toString()%>',<%=StatusCount.get(SC.toString())%>, 'blue'],
            <%  
            }
            %>
            <%for(String EC:EscCount.keySet()){
                %>
                ['<%=EC.toString()%>',<%=EscCount.get(EC.toString())%>, 'red' ],
                <%  
            }
            %>
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Performance',
          },
          is3D: true,
          titleTextStyle: {
              fontName: 'Arial',
              fontSize: 20
          },

          'width':550,
          'height':400,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

        var barchart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

        barchart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
```

`StatusCount` is used for the status count and `EscCount` for the no of escalations. I wanted to change the color of the Escalations bar. But when I specify the color, it's not getting changed. Used the same thing that Google itself has given to change the color.
Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `function drawBarChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Status', 'No. of Issues', { role: 'style' }], 
          
           ['Closed',14, 'blue'],
           
           ['On Hold',8, 'blue'],
           
           ['In Progress',20, 'blue'],
           
           ['Open',24, 'blue'],
           
            
               ['Escalations',4, 'red' ],
               
        ]);`


this the array being passed

Answer (score 1):

[Column Roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles), including `'style'` are only supported by *Classic* charts...

*Classic* --> `google.visualization.BarChart` & `ColumnChart` --> `packages: ['corechart']`

*Material* --> `google.charts.Bar` --> `packages: ['bar']`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Status', 'No. of Issues', { role: 'style' }],
    ['Closed',14, 'blue'],
    ['On Hold',8, 'blue'],
    ['In Progress',20, 'blue'],
    ['Open',24, 'blue'],
    ['Escalations',4, 'red'],
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
  );
  chart.draw(data, {
    theme: 'material'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: `google.charts.Bar` is a _Material_ chart, which does not support the `'style`' role, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) for options...