# Color the bars of Barchart differently in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, django, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am trying to make a barchart using Google Charts and I want to color the bars differently.

From the Documentation of google charts I am sending data from backend in the following format :

```
    {
    "cols": [
    {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms"},{"v":3}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni"},{"v":2}]}
      ]
    }
```

I am using a ajax call to get data from my django backend, the code is shown below -

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: $('#barchart_values').attr('data-actionurl'),
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
    }).responseText;
```

I know I can use the options parameter to set different colors but when I do so only the first color of the list is applied to all the bars.

```
var options = {
      title: "Vegetables",
      legend: { position: 'top' },
      colors: ['green', 'red', 'blue']
    };
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_values'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

In the above code, green color is applied to all the bars.

I want to send the color from the backend, i think I can do it using the "p" attribute, but I don't know how exactly to do it.

#### I want to know is there some way I can include the color in the json data which I am sending from backend. Also why is it so that only the first color provided in the colors list of options is applied to all the bars ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a style column role...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart-bar'));
  chart.draw(new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
      {"label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"},
      {"role":"style","type":"string"}
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms"},{"v":3},{"v":'green'}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Onions"},{"v":1},{"v":'red'}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Olives"},{"v":1},{"v":'blue'}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini"},{"v":1},{"v":'purple'}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni"},{"v":2},{"v":'orange'}]}
    ]
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart-bar"></div>
```

each color in the `colors` option applies to each series in the data
there is only one series in the sample data, `"Slices"`
thus only one color is applied

Comment: any idea how we will do a similar thing on Material bar chart ?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) -- see chart #4...

Comment: so we have to add a spacer column having null values in the DataTable ?

Comment: not required, just creates space between the bars -- take out the spacer to see what i mean..