# Color issues in Google Charts Bar

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I can not generate different colors in google charts bars. The data is coming from a variable `data.addRows([[${golLog}]]);` and I realized that inside this variable has an array. It looks like he throws only the first color for the two bars.

Here is code for understanding:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages' : [ 'corechart','bar' ]
   });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(golLog);

function golLog() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('string', 'Qtd');
   data.addColumn('number');

   data.addRows([[${golLog}]]);

   var options = {
     chart: {
       left:0,
       top:40,
       width:'100%',
       height:'100%'
     },
     title: 'GOL',
     legend: { position: 'none' },
     theme: 'material',
     fontSize: 20,
     colors:['#fc1700','#212e84']
   };

   var chart = new 
     google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_golLog'));

     chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
   }

   <div id="chart_golLog"></div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKVKL.png)

Dados que estão na variável
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Bar Chart cannot Change Individual Bar Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437422/google-bar-chart-cannot-change-individual-bar-color)