# Set Separate Colors for Each Bar With App Script ColumChart Builder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am trying to set a individual color for each bar on a column chart that is rendered using a google app script. I am using the

```
.setColor(["color1", "color2", "color3"])
```

Method. This however leads to all the bars being set to color1. What do I need to change to have each bar be a different color

I have tried using

```
setOption("colors" : ["color1", "color2", "color3"])
```

but this does not work either.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Category")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Score")
    .addRow(["cat1", parseInt(m[0])])
    .addRow(["cat2", parseInt(m[1])])
    .addRow(["cat3", parseInt(m[2])])
    .addRow(["cat4", parseInt(m[3])])
    .addRow(["cat5", parseInt(m[4])])
    .build();

     var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
      .setDimensions(1000, 1000)
      .setDataTable(data)
      .setRange(0,5)
      .setTitle(m[5] + "'s Chart")
      .setColors(["#6c564d", "#db5d52", "#3f4b5d", "#56be93", "#dce24b"])
      .build();
```

I want each category to have its own bar color but the colors are all the first color (category1's color)

Comment: How are you rendering the chart?

Comment: the colors option applies each color in the array to each series in the data -- to have a different color for each bar, each value will need to be in its own column in the data table -- there is another option using a style column role, but this is not available in apps script -- check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) for an example...

Comment: @TheMaster I am using google app script ( https://script.google.com ) column chart builder and then encoding it as base64

Comment: @WhiteHat I don't think that answer applys to me though as that answer is using googles chart api for the web browser, not googles app script service

Comment: that's correct, using apps script, you'll need a different series for each color

Comment: @TheMaster image/png from the chart using Utilities.base64Encode(chart.getAs('image/png').getBytes());

Comment: @WhiteHat So I need to make a column for each category and add one row that holds the data for every category?

Comment: @Liam ok. I think whitehat is right.

Comment: @TheMaster Yah, after taking a better read through what he sent I think hes right as well. I just need a bit more clarification on how I should structure the data table

Comment: one row, with multiple columns...

Comment: @WhiteHat is there a way to make it so that i can set the bar names when using this structure?