# Get Annotation inside the bar - Google Charts Material

Tags: google-visualization

Is there a way to get the annotation inside the bar just like the Google Charts Classic? I am using google Material Charts just to get it Stacked as well as Multi axis.

Also is it possible to have each column have different colors. eg Car-Gas -red, Car-electric - Blue, Truck-gas - orange, Truck-electric - Grey ?

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart", "Bar"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Difference');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Gas');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Gas');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Gas');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Electric');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Electric');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Electric');
    data.addRows([
        ['Car', 216, 319, 190, 20, 14, 40],
        ['Truck', 390, 194, 239, 13, 23, 45]
    ]);


    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        legend: { position: "none" },
        width: 500,
        height: 800,
        
        chart: {
            title: 'title'
        },
vAxes: { 
  0:{viewWindow: {max: 1600} }, 
  1:{viewWindow: {max: 90}}
      },
        series: {
            0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
            1: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
            2: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
            3: {targetAxisIndex: 1},
            4: {targetAxisIndex: 1},
            5: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: there are limitations to using a material chart, among other options, column roles are not supported. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) explains some of your options...